# Inequality Induction Proof: Determining next step

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I have the following induction problem:

Prove that for any non-negative integer n ≥ 0 and a ≥ 0,(1+na) ≤ (1+a)^n.

I proved my base case and now am working on the inductive step (shown below).

[image: Inductive Step]

The problem I'm having is I'm not sure what step to make next. Can I make any conclusions. Part of me wants to say $$(1+b)^{k+1} \ge (1+b)^k+b$$ for $$k\ge0, b\ge0$$ because the arithmetic works out. Yet I'm not confident in that and need to take it a step further and come to a more definitive. Don't want an answer...just someone to help me think though things a bit so I can find the next step  for myself.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: I worked with $$(1+b)^{k+1}$$ a bit and came to something similar to $$(1+b)^k+b$$:

$$(1+b)^k+b(1+b)^k$$

But i am not sure where that puts me

Comment: $(1+b)^{k+1} = (1+b)^k(1+b).  = (1+b)^k + b(1+b)^k$

Comment: You need to prove $(1 +b)^k + b \le (1+b)^{k+1}$. Several things to do but note $\frac {(1+b)^k + b}{(1+b)^k} = 1+ \frac {b}{(1+b)^k} < 1 + b$.....

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that$$(1+b)^{k+1}=(1+b)^k(1+b)\geqslant(1+kb)(1+b).$$

Comment: That is an interesting observation that I didn't see before. I'll see if I can work with it. Thank you .

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To continue your train of thought:

You need to prove

$(1+b)^k + b \le (1+b)^{k+1}$.

Clearly $b < 1+b < (1+b)^k$ so

$(1+b)^k + (1+b)^k = 2(1+b)^k$.  And $2 < 1+b$ so

$2(1+b)^k \le (1+b)(1+b)^k  = (1+b)^k$.

Our you could look at it fromthe other side:

=====old answer ====

You need to *use* your assumption $(1+kb) \le (1 +b)^k$.

So $(1+b)^{k+1} = (1+b)^k(1+b)$ so now use it

$(1+b)^k(1+b) \ge (1+kb)(1+b)$

And from here is *should* all fall into place:

$(1+kb)(1+b) = (1 + kb + b + kb^2)= 1 + (k+1)b +kb^2$

And as $kb^2 \ge 0$ we are done:

......

$(1+b)^{k+1}= (1+b)^k(1+b)\ge$

$(1 + kb)(1+b) = 1 + (k+1)b + kb^2 \ge$

$1+(k+1)b$.

And that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, fleablood. Appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to José Carlos Santos I came up with the following for the inductive step of my proof:
[image: Proof Inductive Step Complete]